# Unity3d Enemy Pushing MainCharacter Back

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a simple game where I want to AI enemy to chase and run to my main character and attack it but before I can get to the point where it is attacking I need to figure out this problem.
When my enemy gets to my main character it keeps going forward and keeps pushing my main character back instead of stopping how can I fix this? Both characters have rigidbodies and colliders.

Thanks

Comment: How are you currently getting the AI to chase the player? Which library/system are you using. The way to solve this problem is diffrent for diffrent libraries.

Comment: You probably move when distance is more than 0, because of the collider size, the player position is in the center and the AI is never at 0. So it keeps walking and rigidbody does the rest. You would have to make the AI move towards the player until he reaches some threshold, like distance > 1

Comment: A dynamic way you can calculate this stopping distance is by calculating half of the width of the enemy and player colliders using their bounds, and only approaching the player when the sum of these widths is less than the distance between the player and the enemy. You'll need to include more information about your current implementation before we can provide any more specific help - for example, if you're using Unity's built-in navigation, there already is a stopping distance specifiable for navigating agents.

Answer (score 1):

The enemy will never be at 0 distance to the player, because the colliders of both player and enemy. It's "impossible" and this means that the enemy will keep on running forward into the player forever.

To fix that, you should set a **minimum distance** for the enemy AI. This way, the enemy won't move unless the player is out of range.

If you're using Unity's default AI or any other kind of AI from the Asset Store, you will probably find this setting on the script controller. Just look at the inspector and check if you can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use "OnCollisionEnter". As far as I know, you could use collider as a trigger of a future action of the enemy and player. Maybe you could set collider in a wider range than that of the characters of yours. Set a specific range that when the player is within that range of the collider it would chase the player and would attack it once it has come to a specific distance then perform the script that you want.